# In reactjs, how do I map an array and add &nbsp; to the return values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reactjs

I'm sure this is simple but I can't find the correct syntax to add nbsp; to each returned valued.

```
let tags = ['foo', 'bar', 'bas']
let rv = (this.state.data.tags.map((tag) => {
  return (<Label bsStyle="default" key={Math.random()}>tag</Label>) + '&nbsp;'})
)
```

I'm just randomly guessing syntax now and wasting time. Can someone suggest the right way to include   at the end of each returned value?

thanks

Comment: @zerkms edited to show it is an array of strings

Comment: The only way to do that is to wrap your element followed by a space with another `<div>` or `<span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `<Label>` and `&nbsp;` in a containing element.

```js
let tags = ['foo', 'bar', 'bas'];
let rv = tags.map((tag, index) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Label bsStyle="default" key={index}>tag</Label>&nbsp;
    </div>
  );
})
```